# "Марафет" - история и этимология слова

Tags: лексика

― Сапогом сыграл, опоздал. **Марафет** подвел, то есть кокаин…  [Г. В. Иванов. Петербургские зимы (1928)]

― Пфа, ― он покрутил головой и объяснил одним словом: ― **Марафет**. [В. А. Каверин. Конец хазы (1924)]

Здесь марафет - это наркотик?

А как он приобрел современное значение: 1. О привлекательном внешнем виде (обычно достигнутом в результате использования косметики). 2. О порядке, наведённом где-л. Навести м. в комнате.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Словарь М.Фасмера:*** Слово: **марафеты**. Ближайшая этимология: подпускать **"одурачивать"**, смол. (Добровольский). Темное слово.
Комментарии Трубачева: [Заимств. из тур. (араб.) mѓrife°t "знание, ловкость, сноровка"; см. Унбегаун, BSL, 52, 1957, стр. 170. -- Т.]

Скорей всего, значение "одурачивать" объясняет современное употребление слова. **Марафет** - на уголовном жаргоне наркотик, *одурманивающий, одурачивающий*.

**Навести марафет** - создать видимость красоты, скрыть беспорядок, недостатки, читай: "одурачить" .